# Using layout_constraintWidth_default with spread or wrap doesn't make difference?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 button and when I am using `layout_constraintWidth_default` with `wrap` and I see there is no behaviour change when I am switching in between wrap and spread and I have `android:layout_width="0dp"` [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` is deprecated, using other suggested ways will result in similar behavior. Deprecated methods may now be just fine, but they were deprecated for a reason, perhaps some unwanted behavior or related to future plans of Android development.

[image]